# cannot find symbol requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

If upgrade 'play-services-games:22.0.1' to 'play-services-games:23.0.0'

I get an error saying 'cannot find symbol requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)'

Why can't I check SCOPE_GAMES(or SCOPE_GAMES_LITE) in the new version?

> ```
>   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
>                                                    .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
>                                                    .build();
>    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(parentContext, gso);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the correct approach is to replace `Games.SCOPE_GAMES` with [the URI as defined in Scopes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes) to create a scope:

```
[...]
.requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.GAMES))
.build()
```

It took me a bit to [find the equivalent for `Games.SCOPE_GAMES_SNAPSHOTS`](https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/android/saved-games#display_saved_games); as the data is stored in the user's Drive app's folder, the scope to use is:

```
[...]
.requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot.
However, Android uses " .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.GAMES)) "
Thanks again :)

Comment: I can highly recommend switching to Kotlin :)